# Logic Negation with Words

Tags: logic

Write the statement “There is no set $A$, for which $A \in A$”, without using words of negation (e.g., ‘no’, ‘not’).

I'm just having a bit of trouble writing this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: For every set $A$ the "sentence" $A\in A$ is false.
There's a better word for sentence, but I can't remember it atm :/

Comment: yea i was thinking theirs a better way to word it

Comment: @AlvinLepik 'statement', perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

$$\left\{A|A\in A\right\}=\phi$$